# "The type already contains a definition for" with a Func and a Method

Tags: linq, overloading, func

I have the following piece of code

```
public static Func<PurchasingDataContext, int, int, List<Requisition>>
    GetRequisitions = CompiledQuery.Compile((PurchasingDataContext context, int userid, int requisitionState)
        => context.Requisitions.Where(r => r.UserId == userid && r.RequisitionId == requisitionState).ToList());

    public static List<Requisition> GetRequisitions(int userid, int requisitionState)
    {
        using (PurchasingDataContext context = new PurchasingDataContext())
        {
            return GetRequisitions(context, userid, (int)requisitionState);
        }
    }
```

and it is producing the following error:

The type 'Purchasing.Data.Requisition' already contains a definition for 'GetRequisitions'

I dont really understand why, I had assumed, perhaps incorrectly that a Func was a method.  In which case I am just overloading here.  Perhaps it is different, or I am just doing something wrong.  Any advice would be great thanks

Will

Answer (score 3):

You have a field called `GetRequisitions` (your `Func` delegate) **and** you have a method of the same name.  That is never allowed.

Comment: So a func is a property in this case?  It is not a method?

Comment: @Wdhough neither property nor method - a *field*, like `public int i;`

Comment: @wdhough - you should mark this as the answer, if it's answered your question